# Why not define all of the attributes of the collection as indexes?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

As I see, when doing `executionStats` command followed to a MongoDB find query, like this:

```
db.users.find({some_index: "hello"}).explain("executionStats")
```

I receive the data with O(1) complexity, since I have pre-defined that `some_index` is index in mongo - using the: `db.users.createIndex("some_index": 1)`

That is great, but why not to define all of the keys as index?

Comment: "I receive the data with O(1) complexity" - that is.... unlikely. For regular btree indexes, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Advantage of indexes:

- Fast Read Queries
- Better Response time
- Helps to make a row unique or without duplicates

Disadvantages of indexes:

- Indexes take additional disk space.
- Indexes occupy RAM
- They decrease performance on inserts, updates, and deletes.

So as the number of indexes for a collection will grow it will decrease the write performance. So it should be created on the fields or collection of fields on which your queries will be maximum.

Comment: Can I determine how many disk space, RAM or some counted resources are used?

Comment: Please read this link you will get all stats regarding indexes . https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Answer (score 1):

> why not to define all of the keys as index?

You can, but the indexes will

1. Take up disk and RAM.
2. Slow down writes.

If you have enough hardware to throw at it, go ahead. But why create and maintain indexes you may not ever need?

Comment: I am trying to understand how the DB can detect a document with O(1) complexity if my indexes are not "sorted properly", I just throw random indexes?

Comment: @Raz  Not sure what you're trying to say here.